# Limit Lebesgue measure of the preimage of a vanishing set (i.e. a set which tends to be empty)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous real-valued function defined over a compact domain $[0, T] \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Let $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\min_{x\in[0, T]} f(x) < c <\max_{x\in[0, T]} f(x)$.

It seems that the following result is true although I don't manage to prove it:

$$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \lvert f^{-1} \left(\ ]c, c+h[\ \right) \rvert = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \lambda\left( f^{-1} \left(\ ]c, c+h[\ \right) \right) = 0$$
where $\lambda(\cdot) = \lvert \cdot \rvert$ is the Lebesgue measure of a measurable set.

If someone comes up with a hint or a reference I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative approach to @ChrisSanders's.

Define for some $\varepsilon>0$, $A_{\varepsilon, n}=(c,c+\varepsilon/n)$. We have $A_{\varepsilon,n}\supseteq A_{\varepsilon,n+1},\,\forall n$. Furthermore, $\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_{n,\varepsilon}=\emptyset$. Also, $f^{-1}(A_{\varepsilon,n})\supseteq f^{-1}(A_{\varepsilon,n+1})$ and $\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}f^{-1}(A_n)=f^{-1}(\cap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}A_n)=f^{-1}(\emptyset)=\emptyset$. If we can use continuity of measures, we have $\lambda(f^{-1}(A_{\varepsilon,n}))\to 0$. We can justify continuity of measures if there exists $\varepsilon>0$ s.t. $\lambda(f^{-1}(A_{\varepsilon,1}))<\infty$. In this case, this $\varepsilon$ exists because $f$ is continuous over $[0,T]$: just choose $\varepsilon=|c-\sup_{x \in [0,T]} f(x)|$. We then have $\lambda(f^{-1}(A_{\varepsilon,1}))\leq \lambda([0,T])=T$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. Can you clarify or reference why the existence of such an $\varepsilon$ ensures the conitnuity of the measure?

Comment: @AdrianJarret [we can use measure continuity from above if $\mu(A_1)<\infty$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Continuity_from_above)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: sets of the form $(c+\frac{1}{n+1},c+\frac{1}{n}]$ are disjoint. So are their preimages. Add up the measures of their preimages. Use facts about absolutely convergent series.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, that's a nice approach to the problem. In this case we actually don't need to rely on continuity arguments for the Lebesgue measure ? Or is it hidden in the decomposition in the sum of measure of disjoint intervals ?

Comment: @AdrianJarret the argument doesn't assume continuity. It assumes additivity, which is an important feature of measures. In fact, the proof of the fact that the measure is continuous uses an argument like the one I gave